# Push to same viewContoller - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a tableViewController from that when I tap on a cell it should push to the same ViewController(for eg:sectionTableViewController -> sectionTableViewController(which will filter some data and show)). I tried to push to the same viewcontroller but I can't. Please help me out. Here is the sample code, i did the sample code in BlipFeedViewController.m

```
BlipFeedHash *feed = [[BlipFeedHash alloc] initWithHash:hashtag];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[BlipFeedViewController viewControllerWithFeed:feed] animated:TRUE];
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to push the same *instance* of your view controller, or another instance of the same view controller? The former is easy: `alloc init` a new one, and push to it. The former is impossible.

Comment: @veddermatic: I believe you meant the latter is easy, the former is impossible.

Comment: Indeed I did! That will learn me to comment pre-coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you filter the data and then do `[tableview reloadData]` instead of creating a new ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Ann's answer is correct. While you could push to another view controller that conains filtered data, that's non-standard and takes more time than if the user could just filter on the same view. Do you have a specific reason why you want another view to display the filtered data? Have you considered the user filtering on the second viewcontroller, and then the third, creating a confusing chain of view controllers?

I beg you, please try to use a more standard filtering interface for the sake of all humanity.